# Mockito: verify the captured object's method is called

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to write a simple unit test. I have a smiple **abstract** class which implements `Runnable`:

```
public abstract class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    doTask();
  }
  public abstract void doTask();
}
```

Then, a function under test uses `MyRunnable`:

```
public class MyService {
  public void something() {
     executor.execute(new MyRunnable() {
        @Override
        doTask() {
          …
        }
     });
  }
}
```

My test case, I want to test `doTask()` has run :

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
   …
   ArgumentCaptor<MyRunnable> myCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyRunnable.class);
   verify(mockMyService).something(myCaptor.capture());

   // get what has been captured
   MyRunnable myRunnable = myCaptor.getValue();
   //verify doTask() has run , but got ERROR.
   verify(myRunnable).doTask();
}
```

My test case throw the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type  and is not a mock!
```

The error complains that `verify()` only accept mocked object. Then, how can I verify/test that the **captured** `MyRunnable` object has run `doTask()` with Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over your codebase, you can make your code testable with Mockito by moving any code that uses the `new` keyword into a separate Factory class like so...

```
public class MyService {

  private MyRunnableFactory = factory;

  public MyService(MyRunnableFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public void something() {
     executor.execute(factory.createInstance());
  }
}
```

Then your test can simply inject a Mock of the factory which you can `verify` its behaviour/interactions

```
@Mock MyRunnableFactory factory;
@Mock MyRunnable myRunnable;

@Test
public void testSomething() {

   when(factory.createInstance()).thenReturn(myRunnable);

   // method under test
   MyService service = new MyService();
   service.something();

   verify(myRunnable).doTask();
}
```

I use a rule of thumb that classes that creates objects, shouldn't have any business logic, so you don't have these testing headaches. This is essentially the [Single Responsibilty Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Thanks, this is also what I am thinking too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Mockito because `MyRunnable` is created by the code under test. But you may have a look at [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) because it allows you to mock the constructor: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Comment: Is there a way to capture mocked MyRunnable instead of real one?

Comment: if you inject an instance of MyRunnable into MyService and you pass a mocked object you should be able to do this